# Custom post type - filter content by custom meta box content

Tags: wp-query, filters

I have custom post type with some products. I need to add some content filtering now. I have custom meta box with "author". I want to add buttons with authors that will act like categories. So let me explain it by example:
I have 3 products: (product num - author)

```
1 - John
2 - Sarah
3 - Tom
```

When I go to my page I see all three products. I want to add 3 buttons on top:

`John| Sarah | Tom`

Every click on button filters results of my query. So by clicking John we see only one product on my site - product 1. 
How to bite this?

I've displayed text with authors using another query_posts() above my original query, but I have no idea what to do next?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your query_posts() results by a custom meta field with the "meta_query" array and its corresponding subfilters. For more information check the Wordpress codex on Custom Field Parameters.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

An alternative method would be to setup the new filter variables in Wordpress' query_vars and use that instead of $_GET:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Custom_Archives

Comment: Thanks for the link. So You think that simply using php for adding clicked values to the link and `$_GET` is a good way of doing this?

Comment: As long as the variables are properly escaped and filtered, there's no reason not to use this method, as it is the simplest way in PHP to handle a form that filters content. I've used similar solutions for filtering content in Wordpress. 

You can also declare new variables in the "query_vars" and use that instead, Wordpress has information in its codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries#Custom_Archives

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe ?

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'author', 'meta_value' => 'john' ) );
// Loop for John ...
wp_reset_post_data()

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'author', 'meta_value' => 'sarah' ) );
// Loop for Sarah ...
wp_reset_post_data()
```

you could separate them with maybe a switch statement.

Probably you will need to pay careful attention to resetting the query, there are three ways to do it. Good post on SE here somewhere explaining the difference.